# how can i assign value to an array in one method and call from another method

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I tried to assign values to an array in main method by calling a method with a parameter
and I want to read it from an another method in that same class but in mines it reads only last elements of the array. Here is an example

```
public void array(int x)
    {
         for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {
            array1[i] = x;
         }          
    }
public void readarray()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("     " + array1[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

in main methods

```
int z;
        for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
          Console.Write($"Enter e values for index {i}:");
            z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            obj.array(z);
        }           
        obj.readarray();
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm very confused as to what this code is supposed to be doing. I do notice that in the second code block you are going from 1 to 6 instead of 0 to 5 though

Comment: Well, your `array`-method overwrites **every** element within the enitre array with the value of the provided argument. As you´re calling that method within a loop, you´re effectivly overwriting the content of the previous loop again and again until you reach the last iteration. I suppose you want to set only a **specific** element within each iteration, don't you?

Comment: @DavidG That doesn't matter here. It's still 5 iterations, where the index doesn't actually matter. What matters is that the whole array is overwritten with the current value ( `z` in main, `x` in `array(x)` ).

Comment: @Fildor I know, I'm just pointing out the inconsistency

Comment: thank you @DavidG  but i think in loop that 1 to 6 thing wont much affect. Because it just for the index

Answer (score 0):

For an explanation to what you experience see comments:

```
public void array(int x)  // Every time this method is called ...
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // you set for index 0 to 4 ...
    {
       array1[i] = x;          // array[index] = x 
       /* so, result is
          array1[0] = x
          array1[1] = x
          array1[2] = x
          array1[3] = x
          array1[4] = x
        */
    }          
}

public void readarray()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("     " + array1[i]); // ALL of your array1[i] are x from
                                                // most recent call to array(x) !
    }
}
```

so, ...

```
for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Enter e values for index {i}:");
    z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    obj.array(z); // <= the whole array[0] to array[4] is now == `z`
}           
obj.readarray(); // will print last value of z for all indices of array!
```

There are some ways you could fix this.

For example, you could pass a specific index to be set:

```
void array(int index, int value){ array1[index] = value; }
```

and use that like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Enter e values for index {(i+1)}:");
    z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    obj.array(i,z);
}           
obj.readarray();
```

---

Of course, there are a lot more issues in that code. Starting with naming conventions, going on with risk of index out of bounds ...
which I will leave to OP and just address the immediate issue from question.